# Is it necessary to always Select()... new{Anon}... AsEnumerable...Select(new EntityType{}) every time?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I keep running into a pattern whereby I want to select rows from an Entity Collection (EF4) and use the data to create new rows in a different entity collection.

The only way I have found to do this is to perform the following steps:

```
var newEntities = (from e in myentities
  where e.x == y
  select new {
    Prop1 = e.Prop1,
    Prop2 = e.Prop2+e.Prop3,
    Prop3 = DateTime.Now,
    Prop4 = "Hardcodedstring"}
  )
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(n=>new OtherEntity{
     Prop1 = n.Prop1,
     Prop2 = n.Prop2,
     Prop3 = n.Prop3,
     Prop4 = n.Prop4}
  );

//insert into database and save
```

If I try to create a new OtherEntity in the select then I get an EF exception.

Is this the only way to proceed?  Makes the whole thing very cumbersome and seems a complete waste of keystrokes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my favorite solution for this is to create a `Convertor` class, that takes `Source` parameter (either list or single object) and transfer it (*create new instance and assign values to it*) to the `destination class type`

```
List<OtherEntity> lst = Convertor.ConvertToOtherEntity(newEntities );
```

Comment: I think I'll use some kind of convertor just to keep the code cleaner and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Automapper to map from your entities to your domain objects instead of doing the mapping from within the linq query.

Comment: This is for mapping from entity to entity rather than entity to domain to entity.  I use automapper for entity to viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's the only way.
Until you run AsEnumerable, ToList, etc. the only methods you can call are methods that are mapped by Entity Framework to SQL syntax.
Since the constructor of OtherEntity is not mapped to anything, this is impossible to call it within an Entity context.